# css and razor - make entire grid block the ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, css-grid

I'm not mega experienced in CSS but moreso I'm confused about applying styles in conjunction with some razor-injected links as opposed to what I know about `a href=""`

I've got a bunch of repeating grid parts in this format:

```
<div class="grid-item bkg-smokey service1">
    @Html.ActionLink(@asp_net_mvc_site.Resources.Common.LinkHome, "x", "CLICK-HERE", null, null)
    <div class="my-circle">
        <div class="fas fa-code my-circle-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

They're arranged using the grid notation in the parent, containing `div` class, e.g.

```
index-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "service1 service2 service3 service4 service5"
}
```

I want to make the entire grid box, `service1`, be the link so when a user hovers over the service1 div they can click anywhere on it and not just on the current text-line "CLICK HERE"

Now my inclination would be to change the `div` to an `a href=""` but I want to use razor so I can attribute the routing parameters.

How can I make the whole `div` container above an @Html.ActionLink?

Comment: Perhaps this link can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702495/mvc-how-to-make-a-whole-div-into-an-action-link

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Html.ActionLink can do what you're looking for.

Sounds like you need an custom [Html Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) which will help with reusability.

```
using System;
namespace Application.Helpers
{
    public class BlockHelper
    {
        public static string Block(string target, string someText)
        {
            return String.Format("<a href='{0}'><div class='my-circle'><div class='fas fa-code my-circle-inner'></div></div><p>{1}</p></a>", target, someText);
        }
    }
}
```

This will help with reusability